# Memory_Management BSOD when shutting down or sleeping computer after Win 10 upgrade

Tags: memory, windows-10, bsod, sleep, shutdown

I recently upgraded a Dell D820 to Windows 10, and have been getting a Memory_Management BSOD every time I shut down the computer or it goes to sleep.

The computer runs fine while in use, and has not thrown the error while running. Memtest86 revealed no issues, and I've also ran a Windows Memory Diagnostic to no avail. I've also swapped the installed RAM out with sticks that I know to be functioning.

Not sure what else to try as I can't seem to find any others who are getting this error ONLY at shutdown / sleep.

Thanks!

EDIT:

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ckg0mar2d9x8pd4/100315-11687-01.dmp?dl=0) is the most recent dmp file from C:\Windows\minidump

Comment: You have a bad memory module.

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump so that we can look at them with a debugger